# C# (where) to JAVA

Tags: java, c#

I am porting some C# code over to Java. 
How can I filter element in if/else blok ? 
How to rewrite this in JAVA ?

```
if(items.Where( x => x.rarity == rarity && x.getPriceByQuality(quality) != 0 && x.name.Contains("AA") == isFull).Count() != 0)
```

Comment: Are you in perticular confused by the predicates? (x=>x.rarity==rarity)

Comment: (As an aside, in the C# version, use `.Any()` instead of `.Count() != 0`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (items.stream().filter(x -> x.rarity == rarity && x.getPriceByQuality(quality) != 0 && x.name.contains("aa") == isFull).count() != 0)
```

but this should be nicer:

```
if (items.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.rarity == rarity && x.getPriceByQuality(quality) != 0 && x.name.contains("aa") == isFull))
```